# using QuickBooks SDK in ASP pages on an intra-office server

Tags: asp-classic, sdk, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I am trying to use QBSDK 12.0 (QBXML) to access a QBW file from ASP pages on an intra-office server.

This was working on a testbed PC running IIS, and having QuickBooks and the QuickBooks SDK installed. All the pieces were on the same machine, so whenever serving ASP pages, there was a logged-in interactive user.

The problem comes when switching to the normal configuration, which is a server PC with IIS, NOT logged-in with any interactive user.

If the server has a logged-in interactive user, the calls [to CreateObject(“QMLRP2E”), etc.] work OK. However, the normal state of the server is to not have any users logged-in. In this case, the QBSDK calls always fail.

I also tried setting up a separate PC running as an RDS Server, and accessing it using an RDS Client. But the RDS Server only runs when an interactive user is logged in on the PC it is installed on. In fact, the RDS server has a checkbox to “always run when user logs in”, not “always run when machine turned on”.

Do I really have to have a PC with QuickBooks software logged-in somewhere on the intra-office network in order to user QuickBooks through ASP pages?

Comment: Is there a guide you follow to accomplish this ? I am trying to accomplish this on my own testbed PC and I am not sure where to start on accomplishing this. Is there a guide you follow somewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely have to change the authentication setup on IIS and disable anonymous access. This should cause the pages to run in the context of the user logged into the client.

There are a lot of other factors based on your setup that may cause some other problems... but that's the best answer I can give in the context of the information provided and given that I've never worked with that particular SDK.